# How to load smart contract with web3j

Tags: solidity, web3j, java

In the documentation of web3j (https://docs.web3j.io/4.8.7/smart_contracts/interacting_with_smart_contract/)
it has only the example of calling the contract after deploying.

Is there any function in web3j to load the deployed contract instead?

something like the web3js:
new web3.eth.Contract(contractAbi, contractAddress);

Answer (score 1):

- Place all solidity contracts under src/main/solidity directory
- Add below dependency to build.gradle file

```
      plugins {
            ...
            id 'org.web3j' version '4.8.7'
        }
        solidity {
            executable = './src/main/resources/solc-windows.exe'    // Path to Solc Compiler file
            version = '0.8.0'
        }
        node {
            nodeModulesDir = file("${project.projectDir}/src/main/node")
            version  = '12.16.1'
            download = false
            distBaseUrl = 'http://nodejs.org/dist'
            npmWorkDir = file("${project.projectDir}/src/main/node")
            workDir = file("${project.projectDir}/src/main/node")
        }
```

- Run task(generateContractWrappers), wrapper contracts will be generated under build/generated/sources/web3j/ERC20.java

**- Generate contract instance using above wrapper.
Connecting using websocket URLs**

```
    String wsURL = "";
    String contractAddress = "";
    WebSocketService web3jService = new WebSocketService(wsURL, true);
    web3jService.connect();
    web3j = Web3j.build(web3jService);
    DefaultGasProvider contractGasProvider = new DefaultGasProvider();
    Credentials credentials=Credentials.create(privatekey);
    ERC20 contractInstance=ERC20.load(contractAddress,web3j, credentials,contractGasProvider);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution of loading the contract with web3j.
Download web3j cli and generate the wrapper class to load your contract.

https://greg.jeanmart.me/2019/07/19/generate-a-java-wrapper-from-your-smart-contract/

Answer (score -1):

It's in the docs, they can be a bit confusing but there is a section for it:

https://docs.web3j.io/4.8.7/getting_started/deploy_interact_smart_contracts/

```
YourSmartContract contract = YourSmartContract.load(
        "0x<address>|<ensName>", <web3j>, <credentials>, GAS_PRICE, GAS_LIMIT);
```

Comment: I just shared the portion of the docs and the code example and I get a downvote?
Can someone explain?

Comment: this document is guiding you to deploy and interact the contract, it needs you to deploy and interact with it directly.  However, what I am looking for is something like this: new web3.eth.Contract(abiCode, contractAddress);

Comment: No, read the documentation, assuming that YourSmartContract is a smart contract wrapper, YourSmartContract.load() given an address LOADS it and returns the contract instead of deploying it. YourSmartContract.deploy() would DEPLOY it and then return the contract instance.
If you open the link I shared you'll find the example under "Or use an existing contract:" or in https://docs.web3j.io/4.8.7/smart_contracts/construction_and_deployment/#construction-and-deployment the second code example